# Structr - neo4j

Tags: neo4j, structr

I tried to install Structr- Neo4j and after I used these  commands:
C:\Users\IEUser>cd structr-ui-2.0-SNAPSHOT-201603301445.5616c
C:\Users\IEUser\structr-ui-2.0-SNAPSHOT-201603301445.5616c>jar xvf structr-ui-2.0-SNAPSHOT-201603301445.5616c.jar structr
java -cp lib/*;structr-ui-2.0-SNAPSHOT-201603301445.5616c.jar org.structr.Server

and I've got this error :
INFO: Running in asynchronous mode
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.structr.schema.compiler.NodeExtender
        at org.structr.rest.service.StructrHttpServiceConfig.loadClass(StructrHttpServiceConfig.java:152)
        at org.structr.rest.service.StructrHttpServiceConfig.initializeFromProperties(StructrHttpServiceConfig.java:87)
        at org.structr.rest.service.HttpService.collectServlets(HttpService.java:608)
        at org.structr.rest.service.HttpService.initialize(HttpService.java:400)
        at org.structr.core.Services.createService(Services.java:552)
        at org.structr.core.Services.initialize(Services.java:327)
        at org.structr.core.Services.initialize(Services.java:299)
        at org.structr.core.Services.getInstance(Services.java:147)
        at org.structr.Server.main(Server.java:36)
Feb 14, 2017 4:25:52 PM org.structr.core.Services createService
SEVERE: Vital service HttpService failed to start: Could not initialize class org.structr.schema.compiler.NodeExtender. Aborting

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are running Structr using JRE instead of JDK. Structr needs JDK to dynamically compile classes.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://support.structr.com/article/258) for further details on setting up JDK for Structr.

Comment: I installed the Jdk and I followed this documentation,but i get the same error.

Comment: Could you please run `where java` and `where javac` in a command shell and post the result?

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>where java
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe

C:\Windows\system32>where javac
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac.exe

C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: It seems you have 2 different versions of java set up in your path and most likely the one under "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" gets called, because it's first in order. Try removing that entry from your java path and see if it works then.